# Compass not compiling magento rwd childtheme everytime

Tags: css, magento, sass, themes, compass

**Update: This seems to be a problem with apache since it happens to other none magento/compass projects**

The compilation itself does not run into any trouble. However with the following considerations the browser does not allways show the changes I have made to the scss file

-Browser cache disabled

-Magento cache disabled

-Apache2 reloaded

-Compass output correct in terminal

I compile sass with compass with the command:

```
compass watch
```

**What gives? Why are not the changes I make showed every time but only sometimes?**

Here is the output logg of the

> > > Change detected at 02:52:38 to: styles.scss
> > >           overwrite ../css/styles.css 
> > >       Change detected at 02:52:54 to: styles.scss
> > >           overwrite ../css/styles.css
> > >       Change detected at 02:53:16 to: styles.scss
> > >           overwrite ../css/styles.css

Even with this output nothing changed but if I wait for a while the changes will come through...

This is the config.rb file:

```
# note: this should never truly be refernced since we are using relative assets
http_path = "/skin/frontend/electrotheme/default/"
css_dir = "../css"
sass_dir = "../scss"
images_dir = "../images"
javascripts_dir = "../js"
relative_assets = true

output_style = :compressed 
environment = :production
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error here is in the lamp installation, after reinstalling lamp on my ubuntu operation system it works just fine now to run

```
compass watch
```

The compilation is almost imidiate when I save.